# Apply CSS value to entire domain from one file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, global

I am trying to do the following:

1. Create a CSS file - lets say it contains:

   ```css
   #elementID{
       Background:black !important;
   }
   ```
2. Create a reference to the script containing my CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
```

3. Apply the css contained within 'global.css' to ALL pages within my domain. I can only reference this script from this one page.

NOTE:
-I am referencing the script from a separate domain (but I can embed directly into the HTML if needed)

-I am trying to get this to work in IE compatibility mode specifically

Is this possible in any way? 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use javascript for do that.

```
<script type="application/javascript">

      if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1)
      {
        document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCssForChrome.css" />');

      }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1)
      {
        document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCssForFirefox.css" />');

      }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1)
      {
        document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCssForSafari.css" />');

      }else if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("op") > -1)
      {
        document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCssForOpera.css" />');

      } else {
        document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCssForIExplorer.css" />');

      }


    </script>
```

Instead of user Agent get the domain path from the document and check wich domain you want to change the css.

Comment: Thank you! Won't this only apply the stylesheet to the current document though? I'd need something that goes on one page and is applied to a.html and b.html without embedding anything within b.html

Comment: Just put this script in a file and load on bothsides, top or bottom or when your window.load